How to safely fix and migrate pip3 packages installed and run using sudo/root/local users to a safe pip3 virtual environment (venv)?
I am running an Ubuntu 22.04 Lemp Server, and I'm not sure I fully understand pip3 and how it works. When installing certain python3-pip packages, some of them required being installed and run as root or sudo user due to the fact that they use/modify/update web server files in root user directories such as /var/www/html or /var/... or /whatever/.../whatever.
To keep my pip3 packages up to date, I have created a root crontab with the following line:
@weekly pip3 freeze > /root/pip3-upgrade-requirements.txt && cd /root/ && pip3 install --upgrade -r /root/pip3-upgrade-requirements.txt

The problem is, that I think (not positive) I installed most of my pip3 packages as sudo user, because I run some of them as sudo user. That was a mistake because (NOW) I know it is dangerous to run/install python3-pip packages as root, because it could somehow download malware or untrusted packages from pip3 repos and override pip3 packages checked and installed by the Ubuntu distribution.
I've done a good amount of reading and many suggest that the proper way to install pip3 packages is to install them in a virtual environment using .venv. Then after a sudo pip3 install command I noticed the following warning:
WARNING: Running pip as the 'root' user can result in broken permissions and conflicting behaviour with the system package manager. It is recommended to use a virtual environment instead: https://pip.pypa.io/warnings/venv

If you could help me expand my understanding of pip, I'm a bit confused about

Where my pip3 packages get installed to when I use sudo pip3 install package-name
Where my pip3 packages get installed to when I use pip3 install package-name
If my pip3 packages are being downloaded from my Ubuntu distribution's repository where there are checked for security holes and bugs, passing the maintainers testing, or if they are being download directly from a pypi pip3 repository where downloads and updates haven't been checked by Ubuntu maintainers for security holes.
The difference between running a pip3 application as sudo, or as regular user
The difference between installing pip3 packages as sudo, or as regular user
The difference between upgrading pip3 packages as sudo, or regular user
The difference between upgrading pip3 packages with the commmand

sudo pip3 freeze > /root/pip3-upgrade-requirements.txt && sudo pip3 install --upgrade -r /root/pip3-upgrade-requirements.txt

, or the command
pip3 freeze > ~/pip3-upgrade-requirements.txt && pip3 install --upgrade -r ~/pip3-upgrade-requirements.txt


The difference between upgrading pip3 packages with the commmand

sudo pip3 freeze > /root/pip3-upgrade-requirements.txt && sudo pip3 install --upgrade -r /root/pip3-upgrade-requirements.txt

or the command
sudo pip-review --auto


The difference between upgrading pip3 packages with the command

pip3 freeze > ~/pip3-upgrade-requirements.txt && pip3 install --upgrade -r ~/pip3-upgrade-requirements.txt

or the command
pip-review --auto


How to check if my root pip3 packages have resulted in broken permissions and conflicting behavior with the system package manager or not.
How to fix any broken permissions caused by a sudo pip3 install.
How to check and verify if my pip3 packages have been installed in/by root or in/by local user.

I need to know all of these things so I can better understand how to accomplish my ultimate goal, and the main question in this post. That question is is...
How can I properly fix my pip3 package permissions, and then migrate the pip3 packages installed using sudo and local user to a virtual environment, and then SAFELY download, update, and use my pip3 packages?
Any help with clear/concise answers and step by step instructions would be much appreciated. Any help with a better general understanding of pip3 would also be appreciated. Thanks!

development tool question fit more on stackoverflow.com

How can I migrate this to stackoverflow? Or do i need to erase and repost?

you have two options, mark your own question for movement by flagging or your second choice
